# Cannot get into CodeBlocks forum

Tags: codeblocks

Downloaded, installed CodeBlocks but can't get into the Codeblocks Forum. If I click on the visit Forum link inside of Codeblocks it takes me to, https://forums.codeblocks.org/
There I look for the Forum but see none, but do see a Menu heading at top says Forums,
Click that and nothing happens, same page (no Forum, just other stuff).
So I look over to left menus and click Forums, nothing, same page. I tried with both Firefox and MS Edge (win10).
So I search and only find one reference to this, it's on Youtube where a guy shows how to put 2 projects in one workspace of CodeBlocks. At first part of video he has very similar issue getting into the Forum. But he just continues with his excellent video on the 2 projects and doesn't say if he ever got into the forum. His video is at,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHGIIp3rGO8
I kinda would really like to get into the forum.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the CodeBlocks forum is going through an infrastructure migration, hopefully they get it fixed soon. I surmise the guy's issue in the video link was not this same migration since his video posted Youtube back in May 4, 2020.